# How to calculate the 90th percentile in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentile

I need to calculate the 90th percentile of a list of values like this:

```
0.0099
0.0129
0.0031
0.0219
0.2632
0.0124
0.0493
0.05
0.0433
```

How would I go about the calculation? I know the answer that is `0.0713,9`. Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(DATA float)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0099)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0129)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0031)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0219)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.2632)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0124)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0493)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.05) 
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0433)

SELECT DATA
FROM @Temp
ORDER BY DATA ASC

--90th percentile 
SELECT ((
        SELECT TOP 1 DATA
        FROM   (
                SELECT  TOP 90 PERCENT DATA
                FROM    @Temp
                WHERE   DATA IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY DATA
                ) AS A
        ORDER BY DATA DESC) + 
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 DATA
        FROM   (
                SELECT  TOP 10 PERCENT DATA
                FROM    @Temp
                WHERE   DATA IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY DATA DESC
                ) AS A
        ORDER BY DATA ASC)) / 2.0
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? if you know how to do the math, you should be able to do it in sql as well...

Comment: Show us the math please, then we can help you with the Sql

Comment: There is no value of 0.0713 in your list, are you misunderstand what is percentile?

Answer (score 5):

- [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

> A **percentile** (or a centile) is a measure used in statistics indicating the value below which a given percentage of observations in a group of observations fall. For example, the 20th percentile is the value (or score) below which 20 percent of the observations may be found.
>
> There is no standard definition of percentile

---

**The Nearest Rank method :**

```
SELECT DATA
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATA, 
        COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) As N, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA) AS i
    FROM @Temp) t
WHERE
    i = ROUND(N * 90.00 / 100.00, 0, 0)
```

---

**The Linear Interpolation Between Closest Ranks method :**

```
DECLARE @P real = 90.00

SELECT MAX(tt.Pv)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (CASE 
            WHEN i = k THEN DATA
            WHEN k = 0 AND P = MIN(CASE WHEN P > @P THEN P END) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) THEN 
                DATA + N * (@P - P) / 100 * (MIN(CASE WHEN P > @P THEN DATA END) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) - DATA)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Pv
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *,
            100.00 / N * (i - 1.00 / 2.00) AS P,
            CASE
                WHEN @P < 100.00 / N * (1 - 1.00 / 2.00) THEN 1 
                WHEN @P > 100.00 / N * (N - 1.00 / 2.00) THEN N
                WHEN @P = 100.00 / N * (i - 1.00 / 2.00) THEN i
                WHEN @P > 100.00 / N * (i - 1.00 / 2.00) THEN i
                ELSE 0
            END AS k
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                DATA, 
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) As N, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA) AS i
            FROM @Temp) ti) t
    ) tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

0.0713 is not a right answer, procentile is a value from the list

```
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE(DATA float)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0099)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0129)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0031)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0219)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.2632)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0124)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0493)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.05) 
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0433) 

select max(case when rownum*1.0/numrows <= 0.9 then DATA end) as percentile_90th
from (select DATA,
             row_number() over (order by DATA) as rownum,
             count(*) over (partition by NULL) as numrows
      from @Temp
      where DATA is not null
     ) t
```

FROM [T-SQL: Calculating the Nth Percentile Value from column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906283/t-sql-calculating-the-nth-percentile-value-from-column)

Answer (score 0):

PERCENTILE_CONT function:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(DATA float)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0099)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0129)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0031)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0219)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.2632)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0124)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0493)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.05) 
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(0.0433)

SELECT
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.DATA) OVER () AS PERCENTILE
FROM @Temp AS e
```

Comment: Given that this is a window function, I'd add `DISTINCT` to the query, or `TOP 1`. Otherwise, you'll get tons of redundant identical values.